# Pandas: if list contains elements from another list (x) , add matching element of x to a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
col1    col2     col3     
1       ab       ['p','q','r','s']
2       rx       ['t','u','v','w']
3       pq       ['h','a','g','s']
```

and another list `x=[g,t,r,c]`

I want to create a new column `col4` that will have the elements that match from `col3` with list x.

After the execution of code, the data frame will look like this:

```
col1    col2     col3                  col4
1       ab       ['p','q','r','s']      r
2       rx       ['t','u','v','w']      t    
3       pq       ['h','a','g','s']      g
```

Here is what I've  tried:

```
x=['g','t','r','c']
for i in df['col3']:
    if (any(elem in i for elem in x)):
        df['col4']=x
```

for which I'm getting this error `ValueError: Length of values does not match the length of index`

Comment: Is col2 relevant to the question?

Comment: Also does col3 contain lists or strings?

Comment: Does col3 contain a list? How? Or is it just a string with letters?

Comment: @ePi272314 col3 contains a list of string characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
s=df.col3.str.join(',').str.get_dummies(',').reindex(columns=x,fill_value=0)
df['new']=s.dot(s.columns)
df
Out[290]: 
   col1 col2          col3 new
0     1   ab  [p, q, r, s]   r
1     2   rx  [t, u, v, w]   t
2     3   pq  [h, a, g, s]   g
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that in one line like so:

```
df["col4"] = df["col3"].apply(lambda v: list(set(v).intersection(x)))
```

Here is a full working example:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 3],
                    "col2": ["ab", "rx", "pq"],
                    "col3": [['p','q','r','s'], ['t','u','v','w'], ['h','a','g','s']]})
x = {'g','t','r','c'}

df["col4"] = df["col3"].apply(lambda v: list(set(v).intersection(x)))
print(df)
#   col1 col2          col3 col4
#0     1   ab  [p, q, r, s]  [r]
#1     2   rx  [t, u, v, w]  [t]
#2     3   pq  [h, a, g, s]  [g]
```

Answer (score 2):

This one line should be enough by using list comprehension:

```
df['col4'] = [ list(set(x) & set(df['col3'][i]) for i in range(len(df['col3']))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` method like so

```
df['col4'] = df['col3'].apply(lambda y : [k for k in y if k in x])
```

If there are multiple matches, that's also taken care of

`[k for k in y if k in x]` is a list comprehension method that gives you a list of elements common in both `x` and `y`, and `y` here is the individual elements of `col3`. If your're sure that there's exactly one match, then you can do

```
df['col4'] = df['col3'].apply(lambda y : [k for k in y if k in x][0])
```

Answer (score 1):

We can iterate through a cartesian of column 3 and x to get the results. Also, faster :)

```
from itertools import product, chain

output = list(chain.from_iterable(set(first).intersection(last) 
                    for first, last in product(df.col3, [x]))
                    )

output 

['r', 't', 'g']


df['output'] = output


  col1  col2    col3    output
0   1   ab  [p, q, r, s]    r
1   2   rx  [t, u, v, w]    t
2   3   pq  [h, a, g, s]    g
```

Comment: I get `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`

Comment: i just edited the code. I just ran it again to confirm the output. what do you get for ```output``` ? or is  your data more than three rows, as shared above?